# Android: first activity after background

Tags: android, android-activity, background, android-manifest, launch

I get a problem when I running a app and the app goes to background. If I click on app icon again It shows activity mark as LAUNCHER:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginScreen" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/defaultStyle">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>            
</activity>
```

But I want to show last activity active before background. It is something wrong on my AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

write `android:launchMode="singleTask"`  in the manifest

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't work, activity mark as launcher still shows when I back from background, any other idea?

Comment: can you give some more details.. if posible give an example of your scenario

Comment: These are the steps: 1. I start the aap and MAIN activity are show 2. I navigate between diferent activites 3. The app goes to background when I was on activity number two (for example) 4. I back to app again and I see MAIN activity (I expected to see activity number two)

Comment: did you finish activity 2 in onpause?

Comment: Can you press back button, Does it navigates to the previous case?? The same happens for me.